# openCV - What do the different stitching parameters mean?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I searched over all the websites and OpenCV documentation to understand the Image stitching parameters (cf below), but it seems that there is no explanation about those anywhere ! Multiple users already asked questions about those parameters, but I didn't manage to find a proper answer.

The parameters are :

```
setRegistrationResol( );
setSeamEstimationResol( );
setCompositingResol( );
setPanoConfidenceThresh( );
```

Could someone please provide a proper explanation about those parameters and how to find the suited values.

Thank you.

Comment: [This](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/introduction.html#stitching-pipeline) probably won't directly answer your question but it should be a good starting point for you to understand the Stitcher class in general. I'd also recommend reading the paper in references